# How can I set appointments to default to current date and time in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

When I create a new reminder for the Outlook calendar, I'd like the date and time to default to the current date and time.  How can I do that in Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Go to File > Options > Calendar. Then you should see an option that says "Default reminders for new items". You can select the current date and time as the default here.

See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-default-reminder-time-58414862-1a3a-4344-ad15-a5f14a750e95